# Why some functions do not ignore null values in R?

Tags: r, function, null, na

I have a time series of daily returns. Observations for which no data were available have value `NaN`.

Trying to apply functions such as `StdDev` from the `PerformanceAnalytics` package the function correctly performs calculations and returns the standard deviation for only the not Null values.

Trying to apply functions such as `mean`, `min`, `max`... return instead a wrong result, i.e. `NaN`.

There is probably something to specify in the "`mean`" function?

Answer (score 4):

From [`?mean`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/mean.html):

> `na.rm`
>
> a logical value indicating whether NA values should be stripped before the computation proceeds.

`min` and `max` also take an `na.rm` argument.

Finally, it may be worth familiarizing yourself with [`?na.omit`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/na.fail.html).

Comment: How can we consider that under the apply function "apply(IndexRet,2,mean)"?

Comment: @LorenzoRigamonti: `apply(IndexRet,2,function(x)mean(x,na.rm=T))`

Comment: `apply` can pass parameters to functions. Use `apply(IndexRet,2,mean, na.rm=TRUE)`.