# replace values with NA in R

Tags: r, sum, na

I have a character vector that looks like:

```
"Internet" "Internet" "-1"       "-5"       "Internet" "Internet"
```

I want to **replace** all values that would be *negative numeric values* (-1, -5, etc)
with `NA`.

I did that with this code:

```
hintsData$WhereSeekHealthInfo[hintsData$WhereSeekHealthInfo < 0] <- NA
```

That seemed to work:

```
head(hintsData$WhereSeekHealthInfo)
# [1] "Internet" "Internet" NA         NA         "Internet" "Internet"
```

But then when I did

```
> sum(hintsData$WhereSeekHealthInfo == "Internet")
# [1] NA
```

Basically I couldn't sum the values anymore because I changed the vector in some way?

Prior to running the NA code I was able to run the code and get this:

```
> sum(hintsData$WhereSeekHealthInfo == "Internet")
# [1] 1691
```

So, how can I replace the "-1", "-5" etc values with NA, but still get:

```
> sum(hintsData$WhereSeekHealthInfo == "Internet")
# [1] 1691
```

Please let me know if you have an idea. I did find other questions about replacing with NA but as I don't know why I can't count values anymore once I replace with NA I'm not sure what to search on or rule out.

Comment: use `na.rm = TRUE` inside `sum`.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706876/r-script-removing-na-values-from-a-vector (or) this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617876/why-some-functions-do-not-ignore-null-values-in-r

Comment: Just another Question? Are the quotation marks important? Then you should replace the numbers with "NA" or is that just a typo?

Comment: Thanks to you both, I just wasn't thinking of it the right way. It works now. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sum` has  a `na.rm` argument, set that to `TRUE`, and you will remove the `NA`. (in general, `1+NA = NA`, so you want to remove the `NA` values)

That being said, you are being slightly sneaky with your `<0` condition given that your vector is character (it does work in this case, but I wouldn't want to presume it was robust)

The idiomatic approach to setting `NA` values in `R` is to use `is.na<-`, eg

```
is.na(hintsData$WhereSeekHealthInfo) <- hintsData$WhereSeekHealthInfo <0
```

Depending on how you read in your data, you could set up this to process your information

Eg, if you knew the valid responses prior to reading in a text file, you could create your own class

```
 setAs("character","Q1", function(from) factor(from ,levels = c('Internet','Newspaper'))

 read.csv('mytextfile.csv', colClasses = list(WhereSeekHealthInfo = 'Q1')
```

or perhaps (being more explicit about NA values and less explicit about what valid values are.

```
  setAs("character","Q1b", function(from) {is.na(from) <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(from)) <0;from})
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this, is that  `x == NA` returns `NA` for any value of `x` (even if `x` is itself `NA`).

So you should use Arun's suggestion, `sum(..., na.rm=TRUE)`